# Acceder a documento desde dos visores PDF con javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Amigos, estoy en un proyecto web en el cual cuenta con dos visores de archivos pdf, uno con estilo (excentricidades del cliente) y otro sin estilos (por si el usuario no quiere ver eso estilos), como el titulo lo indica, al momento de cargar la pagina carga el archivo pdf del servidor y lo muestra, todo bien todo correcto y yo que me alegro, al momento de cambiar al segundo visor por medio de un botón, el nuevo visor carga otra vez el pdf, el problema, que los documentos son de 100mb o mas y algunos usuarios no tienen una conexión excelente y reportan que les demora la carga (¿y que esperaban con tener una conexión pésima?) por lo que se me ha ocurrido una idea para solucionar eso, es que al momento de acceder el primer visor al pdf este se almacena en un espacio de memoria, y mi idea es acceder mediante javascript a ese espacio de memoria con el segundo visor, no sé si será posible esto, y como podría hacer eso, y si de ser posible ¿Cómo lo implementaría?

**NOTA:** Para los visores se utiliza la librería de pdfjs, asi mismo el visor.

Visor 1 Con estilos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visor 2 Sin estilo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen se ve la carga del pdf por parte de Chrome y es a esto lo que quiero apuntar con el segundo visor sin tener que volver a descargar los datos, si ya están solo es de acceder a ellos, ¿o no?
Les agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de `localStorage` agregándolos en base64 y antes de salir de la pagina limpiar.
Para no estar limpiando podrías utilizar `sessionStorage`.

Espero te sirva.